# Ejecutar función al seleccionar un checkbox en wxPython

Tags: python, wxwidgets

Necesito que al tildar el `CheckBox` me cree un `TextCtrl`. Como hago??

Intente con esto:

```
adi2 = self.adi2 = CheckBox(p2, -1, "Sala VIP")
grilla.Add(adi1, pos = (4, 1), span = (1, 1))
```

Y para que me cree el `TextCtrl` hice esto

```
if self.adi1.GetValue():
    caja=TextCtrl(p2,-1," ")
    grilla.Add(caja, pos=(4,2))
```

Si bien no me tira ningún error, no ejecuta nada.

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y **[¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc**. Puedes consultar aquí [qué funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Comment: Hola Matias, debes proveer un [mcve] en caso contrario va a ser difícil dar una respuesta. ¿Dónde están esos dos fragmentos de código? Por ejemplo, si están en el mismo método (por ejemplo en el __init__) no va a funcionar porque en ese punto el CheckBox va a estar desmarcado...  Y lo que se haga después no va a tener efecto. ¿La idea es que nada más marcar el Check se cree el Text o usas un botón por ejemplo para aplicar los cambios y que cree el widget si el check está marcado?

Comment: Si quieres que justo al marcar el `CheckBox` ocurra algo debes enlazar el evento `wx.EVT_CHECKBOX` con la función.